# In Adobe Acrobat Javascript, how can I force a page to become "editable" before a certain part of a script acts upon it?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, adobe-javascript

**What I'm trying to do:** Iterate over each page in a PDF, and extract the number of words on each page.
**What is happening instead:** The code below will return 0 words for any page that has not become "editable". Although I have selected for all pages to become editable at once, Adobe will not maintain the editability of a page for very long after I have left that page. Side note: It also seems to cap how many pages I can have "editable" at once. This is a problem because right now I'm working with a 10 page selection of a pdf file. This same code will have to work with a 120+ page pdf. Please click 'Edit PDF'-->'Scanned Documents'-->'Settings' to see what I mean by "editable".  I have already selected the option to have all pages become editable at once.
**What I've tried so far**: I've tried various ways to get Acrobat to make the page being iterated upon the "active one" so that it would become editable. I've tried manually setting the page number after each iteration of the for loop, and including an artificial delay like with the h variabled for loop in the sample code. I've tried looking for some sort of method that determines which page is the "active one" but I've had no luck so far.

```
CurrDoc = app.activeDocs[0]
CurrDoc.title;
NumPagesInDoc = CurrDoc.numPages;

console.println("Document has "+NumPagesInDoc+" pages");
for (j=0; j<NumPagesInDoc; j++)
{
     
    NumWordsOnPage = CurrDoc.getPageNumWords(j);
    CurrDoc.pageNum = j;
    
    for(h=0; h<10000;h++); //<--I've tried adding in delays to give time so that 
                           //Acrobat can catch up, but this hasn't worked.
    
    console.println("Page number: "+j+" has this number of words: "+ NumWordsOnPage);
    
    
        
};
```

**Output:**

```
Document has 10 pages
Page number: 0 has this number of words: 309
Page number: 1 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 2 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 3 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 4 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 5 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 6 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 7 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 8 has this number of words: 0
Page number: 9 has this number of words: 158

true
```

**Note**: Different pages might work on the output at different times depending on which pages I've clicked on most recently before running the script.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. **Thank you** for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So. I'm still not entirely sure what the issue is, but I've found a way to get acrobat to function most of the time.

Before clicking the "make all pages editable" option, zoom all the way out until you can see all the pages in the document. For whatever reason, when I did this, it would seem to refresh something about the settings and once again make all the pages editable. This even seemed to work when I opened a totally different pdf and pressed "make all pages editable" even without zooming out.